# VS2019 or VS2022 iOS Xamarin "Remote Device" not show

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2019, publish, visual-studio-2022

I want build my iOS application for Apple store but i don't find "Remote Device".
My VS2019 for windows ver. is 16.11.9.

As I have always done I connect via VPN to the network where a MAC is connected, but visual studio still does not show me "Remote Device".
I search the net and discover that it was a problem of version 16.11.0 fixed in version 16.11.3
I install visual studio 2022 but same problem, I see all the emulators, "Local device" but no "Remote device".

How can I publish on the Apple store?

Some idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts to reconnect, I noticed that among the devices there was also a physical device (iPhone) connected directly to the MAC.
I used that and it worked !! :-))

So I could assume that if visual studio sees a connected iPhone it hides the "Remote Device" option